# Simplest way to get the equivalent of "find ." in python?

Tags: python, file, find, filesystems

What is the simplest way to get the full recursive list of files inside a folder with python? I know about `os.walk()`, but it seems overkill for just getting the unfiltered list of all files. Is it really the only option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive sub folder search and return files in a list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394147/recursive-sub-folder-search-and-return-files-in-a-list-python)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from creating your own function:

```
import os

def listfiles(folder):
    for root, folders, files in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in folders + files:
            yield os.path.join(root, filename)
```

You can use it like so:

```
for filename in listfiles('/etc/'):
    print filename
```

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to make sure this function wasn't already a part of the standard library.

Comment: Nice solution! But `find .` also lists directories. The fix is very easy though. :)

Answer (score 13):

`os.walk()` is not overkill by any means. It can generate your list of files and directories in a jiffy:

```
files = [os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
    for (dirpath, dirs, files) in os.walk('.')
    for filename in (dirs + files)]
```

You can turn this into a generator, to only process one path at a time and safe on memory.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `find` program itself from Python by using [sh](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/index.html)

```
import sh
text_files = sh.find(".", "-iname", "*.txt")
```

Comment: `sh` is not a builtin, by the way. I assumed it was because it sounded familiar.

Answer (score 2):

[`pathlib.Path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) is pretty simple. It lists the entire directory tree

(The argument is a filepath search pattern. `"*"` means list everything)

```
import pathlib


for path in pathlib.Path("directory_to_list/").rglob("*"):
    print(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either that or manually recursing with [`isdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) / [`isfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) and [`listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) or you could use [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and call `find .`. Bascially `os.walk()` is highest level, slightly lower level is semi-manual solution based on `listdir()` and if you want the same output `find .` would give you for some reason you can make a system call with `subprocess`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
path = "path/to/your/dir"
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
    print files
```

Is this overkill, or am I missing something?

Comment: You are absolutely right. It looks way more difficult than it actually is.

Answer (score 1):

os.walk() is hard to use, just kick it and use pathlib instead.

Here is a python function mimicking a similar function of list.files in R language.

```
def list_files(path,pattern,full_names=False,recursive=True):
    if(recursive):
        files=pathlib.Path(path).rglob(pattern)
    else:
        files=pathlib.Path(path).glob(pattern)

    if full_names:
        files=[str(f) for f in files]
    else:
        files=[f.name for f in files]
    return(files)
```