# Using python iterators to recursively list files in a folder

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I am trying to list all the TIFF files in a folder using python. I found an answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394147/recursive-sub-folder-search-and-return-files-in-a-list-python), and adapted its code as follows:

```
import os
import glob
from itertools import chain

def list_tifs_rec(path):
    return (chain.from_iterable(glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.tif')) for x in os.walk(path)))

def concatStr(xs):
    return ','.join(str(x) for x in xs)
```

But I got a runtime error about `'module' object is not callable`, when I tried to execute it as follows:

```
>>> l = list_tifs_rec("d:/temp/")
>>> concatStr(l)

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 9, in concatStr
  File "<string>", line 9, in <genexpr>
  File "<string>", line 6, in <genexpr>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I come from a C++ background and don't know Python generators very well. I googled around and didn't find close examples of this error, probably because of its generality.

Can anyone please explain the error and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: `glob` is a module.  `glob.glob()` returns a list, `glob.iglob()` returns an iterator.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. This was fast. I'll accept in 9 min.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `glob.iglob` (the method), not just `glob` (the module), like so:

```
glob.iglob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.tif'))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to write a generator function that yields the file paths you need.  Similar to your solution but a bit more readable.

```
def foo(root, file_ext):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
        for f_name in filenames:
            if f_name.endswith(file_ext):
                yield os.path.join(dirpath, f_name)
```

usage

```
for name in foo(r'folder', 'tif'):
    print name

files = ','.join(foo('c:\pyProjects', 'tiff'))
```