# python script for searching jpeg files in multiple folders

Tags: python, jpeg

I have a directory which contains multiple directories within it. The sub directories each have jpeg images in them. Can you help me to find a way to extract those images and copy them to a single folder using python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30255302/4889267 this has 90% of the work involved. Check it out

Comment: 1. [Find files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394147/recursive-sub-folder-search-and-return-files-in-a-list-python) 2. [Copy files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2)

Answer (score 0):

you could do for example :

```
import glob, os
from shutil import copyfile

os.chdir("yourdirectory")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpeg"):
    copyfile(file, "destinationdirectory/"+file)
```