# Python: Move only file who filename match with the current date in another dir

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this situation:

On my HD i have this kind of directory structure:

```
   root>
   root>dir1>05-13-2018_xxxxxxxx.TXT<br>
   root>dir1>05-14-2018_xxxxxxxx.TXT <-- today file to copy in another dir<br>
   root>dir2>05-13-2018_xxxxxxxx.TXT<br>
   root>dir2>05-14-2018_xxxxxxxx.TXT <-- today file to copy in another dir<br>
   root>dir3>ecc...
```

i have formatted a python variable who reflect the today date like this `data_oggi = str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))`
i need to scan all subdirs and move the file with match date in filename in another dir...
I'm in empasse,
can anybody help me?
Thank guys for every support.

Comment: Did you go through this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40755802/5413146 ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be using `glob` module to list all matching files in your source directory and moving them to the destination using `shutil`.

I hope following will be helpful:

```
import os

import shutil

import datetime

import glob

BASE = "/root/"

DESTINATION = '/root/test2'

os.path.exists(DESTINATION) or os.makedirs(DESTINATION)

# DIR = 'dir1'
DIR = 'dir1'


def get_file_key():
    """
    Builds file identifier
    """
    return str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))

def move_file(file_path):
    try:
        shutil.move(file_path, DESTINATION)
    except:
        print('file exists....')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    file_for_today = get_file_key()
    files = glob.glob(BASE + '/**/{key}*.txt'.format(key=file_for_today), recursive=True)

    for file in files:
        move_file(file)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Sijan!!This work like a charm and fit my need!!You save my day!