# how to make a launcher to a game that doesn't have a clear place in python?

Tags: python-3.x, launcher

i want to make game launcher with python.But the game's place depends on how you installed it.There's one thing that can help: C:\Program Files (x86)\Electronic Arts, in anyway the game is installed there, the rest of this path depends on the person who installs it, i would make a code which is able to do a search in the given path (it should search for a given checksum) please how can i do that ?
edit: i made something like to get the path and use it but it's not working:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive sub folder search and return files in a list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394147/recursive-sub-folder-search-and-return-files-in-a-list-python)

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable here. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why. Please [edit] your post to provide the code as text, properly formatted for readability.

Comment: I tried to post as you said, but it says that there's faults and I must corrige them, so a posted as pic