# Load medical images from subfolders

Tags: python, operating-system, os.walk, image-loading, loadimage

i try to work with chest x-ray images data from stanford ml group. However, in order to train my data i need to load images from subfolders:

```
chestXray/train/#patiendIDs-here/#studyIDs-here/view-jpeg-files.jpg
```

i tried different ways with os.walk:

```
root='/content'
exclude_files = ''
#exclude_files = read_file.read() csv
samples=[]
samples2=[]



for rt, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(root, 'cHexpert','train')):
    for name in dirs:
        name = os.path.join(root, 'cHexpert/train', name)
        #print(files)
        if name not in exclude_files:
            samples.append(name)

    for file in files:
        file = os.path.join(root, 'cHexpert/train' ,file )
        #print(files)
        if name not in exclude_files:
            samples2.append(file)
```

but the first one gave me these paths:

```
/content/cHexpert/train/patient00006
```

and after a while: `/content/cHexpert/train/study2`

second pile of code gave this which looks more true but it miss some subdictioneries:

```
/content/cHexpert/train/view1_frontal.jpg
```

how to concenate them? thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive sub folder search and return files in a list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394147/recursive-sub-folder-search-and-return-files-in-a-list-python)