# Remove folders but the csv files

Tags: python, windows, shutil

I have a folder (folder_1) that consists of many different subfolders, these subfolders (subfolder_1, subfolder_2, etc etc) all consist of 1 csv file. I'd like to delete all subfolders, and just keep all csv files. Is there a way to achieve this without specifying all subfolders?

Maybe a way to make an exception for csv files using shutil?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think with `shutil` directly, but this should be trivial with `os.walk`. If pure Windows is not a strict requirement, GNU `find` can probably also do this.

Comment: In Total Commander it is more convenient than in Python: Display all files in all subfolders by Ctrl+B, then select all of them (Ctrl+A) and move all them (F6) to an appropriate folder (maybe `folder_1` is your desired target folder). The Ctrl+B again, select all (now empty) folders and press the Delete key.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

1. Loop over the subfolders.
   Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394147/recursive-sub-folder-search-and-return-files-in-a-list-python).
2. Get the csv file(s) path. (replace the .txt to .csv from previous post)
3. Use the `shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")` to move the file on a higher level.
4. use `shutil.rmtree()` to remove folder. (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder) too)