# Python - How do I access a subfolder inside the same folder as my compiled code?

Tags: python, path

I have a simple script that finds an excel file in a subfolder, opens it and converts it to a csv.  I need to automate this to run every day at a certain time.  I hoped to use Task Scheduler to do this.

I found this solution here:  [How to do a recursive sub-folder search and return files in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394147/how-to-do-a-recursive-sub-folder-search-and-return-files-in-a-list)

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('sheets/**/*.xlsx', recursive=True) 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
filelocation = pathlib.Path().resolve()
```

When I compile and run my code as a user, it works fine.  When I run it through task scheduler, it responds with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\\192.168.1.119\Work\exporttoact\ActImport.py", line 26, in <module>
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
[16540] Failed to execute 'ActImport' due to unhandled exception!
```

I ~think~ this means, because I am running through task scheduler, that it does not have access to or cannot see that file share and is returning list_of_files as empty.  Apparently, Task Scheduler opens each running script in a tmp folder in a protected space without the user environment.

How do I add that folder to my path so I am able to access it no matter where my code runs?  I have tried to add via NET USE, but if the user already has the folder mapped (they do) it will not allow a second map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer was actually pretty simple.

In the program I am running, under Task Scheduler->Task->Actions I added the "Start In(Optional)" directory.  It has to be where the .exe is located.