# Loop Directory (folder and Subfolder in Python app)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I am trying to have an app that loops through a directory (folder and sub) searching for multiple extensions or keywords and outputs the list in a dynamic frame but the code (or returns Zero if nothing found).

Current code fails both when multiple extensions (or keywords) are inputted or fails by grouping multiple results in a single row of the frame.

*I need help in debugging my code posted below.*

Thank you

```
   from st_aggrid import AgGrid
    import streamlit as st
    import pandas as pd
    import os

    office= st.text_input("Enter your Office : ")
    path= st.text_input("Enter directory path to search : ")
    extensions= st.text_input("Enter the File Extension :")

    file_names = [fn for fn in os.listdir(path) if any(fn.endswith(ext) for ext in extensions)]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Office' : [office],'Directory' : [path],'File_Name' : file_names})
    AgGrid(df, fit_columns_on_grid_load=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

1. When getting the extension using `st.text_input` the returned value is a string not a list of extension. In order to solve this just ask the user to enter the extension seperated with a comma and split the string to get a list of extensions.

   ```
   extensions= st.text_input("Enter the File Extension (Seperated with comma):").split(",")
   ```
2. when you first run the Streamlit code the values of `office`, `path`, `extensions` are `None` causing a `FileNotFoundError` so we need to run the code to loop through a directory and display files only if the these values are not None.

   ```
    if office and path and extensions:
        # code
   ```
3. Searching file is not recursive so we need to change it to get subfolder files also we can do this using the solution suggested in this question [How to do a recursive sub-folder search and return files in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394147/how-to-do-a-recursive-sub-folder-search-and-return-files-in-a-list). Also we need to check if file has the extension or keyword.

Putting it all together:

```
import os
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import AgGrid

office= st.text_input("Enter your Office : ")
path= st.text_input("Enter directory path to search : ")
extensions= st.text_input("Enter the File Extension (Seperated with comma):").split(",")

if office and path and extensions:
  file_names = []
  file_names_ext = []
  dirs = []
  for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for fn in filenames:
      for ext in extensions:
        if ext in fn:
          dirs.append(dp)
          file_names.append(os.path.join(dp, fn))
          file_names_ext.append(ext)
          break

  df = pd.DataFrame({'Office': office , 'Directory': dirs, 'File_Name' : file_names, 'Term': file_names_ext})
  AgGrid(df, fit_columns_on_grid_load=True)
```

So For example if i have the following folder structure:

[image: Structure]

These are examples of the output of the working code:

[image: out1]

[image: out2]

Comment: Thank you very much! @RoseGod 
would this work also if I want to search for a specific key-word-string series (comma separated) within the file full path in a specified directory?
Lastly, how can I add the related key-word-string, or file extension on a new column in the dataframe to understand why a file was marked for review?

Comment: @Pynew I updated the code to retrieve all files with the specific key-word-string and to add the key-word-string as a a new column. Also if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have accepted it. Last question, how can I modify the search to be Not-Case Sensitive? @RoseGod

Comment: @Pynew Changing the following line `if ext in fn:` to `if ext.lower() in fn.lower():` should solve the case sensitive.

Comment: I posted a new question. I hope you can help.