Confused by for-loop to map conversion which produces different results
I have an existing implementation for a function which uses a for loop.
I want to convert this into a more functional form using a map operation.
My current, working, implementation
This is the function I want to convert:
def _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive(target: str) -> list[str]:
    items:list[str] = []
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        items.append(target)
    elif os.path.isdir(target):
        items.append(target)
        for item in os.listdir(target):
           item = os.path.join(target, item)
           more_items = _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive(item)
           items.extend(more_items)
    return items

My attempt to convert this function, which does not work
This is my attempt to convert it.
def _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive(target: str) -> list[str]:
    items:list[str] = []
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        items.append(target)
    elif os.path.isdir(target):
        items.append(target)
        items.extend(
            map(
                _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive,
                map(
                    lambda item: os.path.join(target, item),
                    os.listdir(target),
                )
            )
        )
    return items

My test directory structure:
You will need this for reproducibility.
example-target-directory/
 example-file.txt
 example/subdir/
  example-file-2.txt

Output
The origial code produces this output. This is what we would expect the second version of the function to produce.
running fast_scandir_3(example-target-directory)
results:
('d', '/home/user/work/python/example-target-directory')
('f', '/home/user/work/python/example-target-directory/example-file.txt')
('d', '/home/user/work/python/example-target-directory/example-subdir')
('f', '/home/user/work/python/example-target-directory/example-subdir/example-file-2.txt')

The new version of the code raises an exception when the function _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_paths_to_path_tuples is called.
Test Case 1
import os

def _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_paths_to_path_tuples(paths:list[str]) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    def path_to_tuple(path:str) -> tuple[str, str]:
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            return ('f', path)
        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            return ('d', path)

    return (
        list(
            map(
                path_to_tuple,
                paths,
            )
        )
    )

def _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive(target: str) -> list[str]:
    items:list[str] = []
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        items.append(target)
    elif os.path.isdir(target):
        items.append(target)
        for item in os.listdir(target):
           item = os.path.join(target, item)
           more_items = _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive(item)
           items.extend(more_items)
    return items

print(_fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive('example-target-directory'))

print(
    _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_paths_to_path_tuples(
        _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive('example-target-directory')
    )
)

These do not print the same thing:
# Test Case 1
user@host:~/work/python$ python3 test1.py 
['example-target-directory', 'example-target-directory/example-subdir', 'example-target-directory/example-subdir/example-file-2.txt', 'example-target-directory/example-file.txt']
[('d', 'example-target-directory'), ('d', 'example-target-directory/example-subdir'), ('f', 'example-target-directory/example-subdir/example-file-2.txt'), ('f', 'example-target-directory/example-file.txt')]

# Test Case 2
user@host:~/work/python$ python3 test2.py 
['example-target-directory', ['example-target-directory/example-subdir', ['example-target-directory/example-subdir/example-file-2.txt']], ['example-target-directory/example-file.txt']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 40, in <module>
    _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_paths_to_path_tuples(
  File "test2.py", line 12, in _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_paths_to_path_tuples
    list(
  File "test2.py", line 6, in path_to_tuple
    if os.path.isfile(path):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen genericpath>", line 30, in isfile
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list

Test Case 2
import os

def _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_paths_to_path_tuples(paths:list[str]) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    def path_to_tuple(path:str) -> tuple[str, str]:
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            return ('f', path)
        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            return ('d', path)

    return (
        list(
            map(
                path_to_tuple,
                paths,
            )
        )
    )

def _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive(target: str) -> list[str]:
    items:list[str] = []
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        items.append(target)
    elif os.path.isdir(target):
        items.append(target)
        items.extend(
            map(
                _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive,
                map(
                    lambda item: os.path.join(target, item),
                    os.listdir(target),
                )
            )
        )
    return items

print(_fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive('example-target-directory'))

print(
    _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_paths_to_path_tuples(
        _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive('example-target-directory')
    )
)

You should find that the first print statement prints a nested set of lists, and not a single list. If you do not observe this behaviour, something is wrong.

I can't figure out why this function returns a list of lists instead of just a list.

Additional Info: map works as expected

Someone suggested in the comments that multiple calls to map produce nested iterators, but I do not find this behaviour. This code produces a single list with no nested lists.

result = (
    list(
        map(
            lambda x: x + 1,
            map(
                lambda x: x + 2,
                map(
                    lambda x: x + 3,
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

print(result) # [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]


I have stripped a bit of extra code out - two functions which were not strictly speaking necessary.

Note that os.walk might work as a replacement for your recursive function.

@9769953 yes, but I didn't want to include all of this additional print stuff in the question as it begins to become rather large.

You cannot hope to debug this by looking at it. Just copy and paste it into your REPL and get a stack trace. do is something I just added to try and debug this.

@9769953 You cannot possibly be running the same code as me. Can you send me your code via chat?

@9769953 That's because you're running the script with a path that doesn't include subdirectories (so you won't get any nested lists in the output of _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive).

@9769953 Then you must be doing something else different. The two _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive functions at the start of the quesion do not produce the same output.

@ekhumoro No, this is not correct either. My directory structure looks like this: -example-target-directory, example-target-directory/example-subdir, example-target-directory/example-file.txt, example-target-directory/example-subdir/example-file-2.txt

@ekhumoro Yeah - that's the whole point of this question.

@user2138149 I was replying to 976993, who claimed they could not reproduce the problem. I can reproduce the problem, but only if I use the second version of _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive in your question.

I have added two very simple test cases which can be copied and pasted to your machine. Please stop saying "this isn't reproducable" - because unless we have a Python version mismatch and some weird bug which has been recently fixed, your machine and my machine should be producing the same outputs, and the 2 outputs from the two implementations are not the same.

@ekhumoro Understood, thanks for clarifying. Please see the two examples at the bottom of this question.

@9769953 You cannot call the function _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_paths_to_path_tuples(paths) with paths set to be a list containing other lists because you cannot call os.path.isfile or os.path.isdir on a list. You must be doing something which isn't the same as what I have posted here.

@9769953 Try this: Call _fast_scandir_3_impl_convert_paths_to_path_tuples with the following argument: [['example-target-dir']]. It must blow up.

@user2138149 Your current question is actually confusing things by adding far too many examples. What I suggest you do is create a single script that only combines the part in "Here's the rest of the code" with the two versions of _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive (but using different names). Then you can easily compare the output from each implementation. (PS: for me, the one answer you already have solves the problem, and explains what causes the problem quite well).

The map(_fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive, ...) applies the recursive function to each path (generated from map(lambda item: os.path.join(target, item), os.listdir(target))), but it returns an iterator of iterators.
This nesting of iterators causes the problem when you try to extend the items list, as extend() expects a flat iterable, not an iterator of iterators.
So you need to flatten the nested iterators. You can use itertools.chain.from_iterable for this for example; it takes an iterator of iterators and flattens it into a single continuous iterable which is what extend() needs.
Try this:
from itertools import chain

def _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive(target: str) -> list[str]:
    items: list[str] = []
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        items.append(target)
    elif os.path.isdir(target):
        items.append(target)
        
        # Flatten the result using chain.from_iterable
        items.extend(
            chain.from_iterable(
                map(
                    _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive,
                    map(lambda item: os.path.join(target, item), os.listdir(target))
                )
            )
        )
    return items

Edit:
I see a downvote and a comment calling the solution wrong, without much of an explanation or more to go from there. So I will try and clarify one more time -

The original function works because it directly extends items with the result of each recursive call, which is a flat list.
The functional approach with map() causes nesting because each recursive call returns a list, leading to an iterator of iterators.
Flatten the result using itertools.chain.from_iterable() to make the functional version work as expected.

Edit 2:
Trying to clarify the confusion you expressed in the comment below on why the output of the map is a list of lists and why flattening is required, let's do a walkthrough:

_fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive() takes in a str as input, and outputs a list[str], as you've rightly claimed in your comment.

map(lambda item: os.path.join(target, item), os.listdir(target) outputs a list[str]. Lets call this joined_items.

So joined_items is a list[str], something like let's say ['usr/path1', 'usr/path2']



So what is map(_fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive, joined_items) doing?

_fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive() is called for each path in joined_items. So the first call would be something like _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive('usr/path1'). We have a list[str] returned as a result. Lets say ["resultString1"] is the output of this function call.
The next call is _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive('usr/path2'). Again, a list[str] is returned, let's say the output is ["resultString2"]
So the map() applied _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive() to both the inputs 'usr/path1' and 'usr/path2' and got back two lists ["resultString1"] and ["resultString2"]. The result of a map() function is an iterable, so it stores the two response lists in an iterable, so we have [["resultString1"], ["resultString2"]] as the output of our map.
However, you cannot pass this output to extend(). You need to flatten it out as ["resultString1", "resultString2"] before you can pass it to extend(). That is what we do with chain_from_iterable() above.


Ah. I forgot python's map function is not a proper map function.

Hmm no, we are both wrong. This isn't the answer. See my added info.

In the example you provided, map() works because each call is simply transforming a single value in the list, which produces a flat iterable as the output.
However, in the recursive case, each call to _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive returns a list of paths. Since os.listdir(target) is a list of directory contents, applying map() results in an iterator of iterators (i.e., a list of lists of paths).
I suppose you downvoted the answer, but could you atleast run it and check if it works, or provide what error you receive on running it?

@Ayush I have not voted on this

@Ayush, if _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive returns a list, then it should be fine to call items.extend with an argument of a list, no?

_fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive returns a list, and this function is called for each path inside os.listdir(target). So for each path inside os.listdir(target) when you call the function and have a list returned, do you see that the final output from the map is now a list of the returned lists(more precisely an iterator of iterators)?
This list of lists needs to be flattened before being provided to extend()

@user2138149 An alternative solution that may make things clearer, is to do for result in map(...): items.extend(result).

@Ayush This function call is wrapped by a map, which iterates over the list. Every time the function _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive is called, it can only take a single str as input, and it can only return a list[str] as an output. This returned list is then iterated over by map. If it isn't behaving this way then something is wrong and I don't understand exactly why.

Ah I think I've got it. You are right. It returns individual files wrapped in 1 element lists. Hmm... how to fix this

@user2138149 Why do you think this answer doesn't already fix it?

@user2138149 I made a 2nd edit to the answer to try and clarify previsely the confusion you expressed in your latest comment with a walkthrough, does that help?
Regarding "how to fix this", I've already provided a solution, did you try it?

@Ayush see my answer - I belive your solution will work, but what it was actually missing was a reduce operation. It's opinion based but imho this is the proper way to fix it becuase it follows the map-reduce paradim, and does exactly what it says it does.

@Ayush I've upvoted you

I believe what matters most is understanding what the problem is, rather than how it gets solved. Both approaches ultimately solve the same issue of flattening nested lists, and there are certainly multiple ways to approach it.
I used chain.from_iterable since it's designed for flattening iterables efficiently. The reduce approach you mentioned is just as valid—it’s about choosing the tool you prefer. Ultimately, the key is recognizing that map() returns a list of lists, which we need to flatten before passing to extend().

Fixed it
Thanks to Ayush for helping direct me towards a solution with this.
def _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive(target: str) -> list[str]:
    items:list[str] = []
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        items.append(target)
    elif os.path.isdir(target):
        items.append(target)
        items.extend(
            reduce(
                operator.add,
                map(
                    _fast_scandir_3_impl_get_paths_recursive,
                    map(
                        lambda item: os.path.join(target, item),
                        os.listdir(target),
                    )
                ),
                [],
            )
        )
    return items


I do not understand why you would go to the trouble of implementing your own recursive function when pathlib.Path.rglob() will do all the hard work for you - and, possibly, faster

@SIGHUP Well that's not the question being asked here. There's no need to be salty because I didn't accept your answer to my other question yet. I'm still working on it

Partly to blame I suppose would be these low-quality reference websites. I think this is where I got the initial idea. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-all-files-in-directory-and-subdirectories/

@SIGHUP I suppose another reason not to use rglob would be that it's supposedly slow. In my particular case I don't think I really care that much about this, at least not at the moment, but it is worth keeping in mind as things scale.

please cite your evidence that rglob is "slow". It may be so but I can't find any proof of your assertion

@SIGHUP maybe things have changed with later releases, but there's multiple posts about it here on Stack Overflow, just do a search for them

@SIGHUP Take a look at these answers, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory

@SIGHUP One of the problems we have here is there are already numerous questions about this subject. But as seen here, not everyone has exactly the same requirements in terms of function specification. Also, over time, things have changed. As much as I would like to ask the question in 2024, what is the best / fastest / most efficient method to find all files and folders recursively including in the case where the target itself is a file there is no point because it will be downvoted and closed as being "opinion based" and other such nonsense. SO is no longer effective

@SIGHUP Basically, over time, software evolves and changes. But the users and moderators of SO don't think it does. They think everything is fixed in time and that a 15 year old question should suffice rather than asking a new one. They will tell you - just add a new answer to that one. But you can't, because it already has 100+ answers, most of which are spam saying "look at this slightly different way of doing X which I have come up with". Then if you add a new answer, people will downvote it because it looks like an attempt at reputation bumping.

@SIGHUP basically, the point being, somewhere on that thread (or maybe another one) someone wrote a fast_scandir function. It's called fast_scandir because it was found to be notably faster than the alternatives - for whatever reason. However this may have been in 2010 or something stupid, so it may no longer be of any relevance. I simply used that function, going by the information which was available to me at the time. I then needed to evolve the function for a slightly different purpose, which resulted in this question.

@SIGHUP Then, when I found an answer I posted the answer which was most closely aligned with what I was originally aiming for. I did not post this to "dab" on you or anyone else's contribution. I posted this because it was what I had envisioned writing in the first place. It's fine for you to propose an alternative method, which may even be better - but that was not what was asked in the question. Look - my point is don't be upset about it. SO has its problems and until those problems are fixed nothing will change.

@SIGHUP btw - if you search for fast_scandir here you will find loads of stuff https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fast_scandir

@SIGHUP see also this answer from 2020: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394147/how-to-do-a-recursive-sub-folder-search-and-return-files-in-a-list

@SIGHUP fast_scandir clearly wins and is twice as fast as all other solutions, except os.walk
